# Force touched on ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, input, required

I want to set requires with the red color in the angular material when I click on "Submit", and for that I need to force an input to be touched.

```
                <div class="formRow">
                    <mat-form-field class="profile-field" style="width: 40%" appearance="outline">
                        <input required #personalInfoFirstName 
                                class="profile-input" matInput
                               placeholder="firstname" name="firstName"
                               [(ngModel)]="firstName" #tst="ngModel">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div>touched = {{tst.touched}}</div>
```

how to set forced touch (tst.touched) to a [(ngModel)]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grabbing `#tst`, you can use `tst.control.markAsTouched()` to change its state.

Comment: well, on the  typescript don't work because #tst="ngModel"

Comment: you can pas **tst** as an argument of your submit function <button (click)="submit(tst)"</button> to use it into the component. r using ViewChild : `@ViewChild('tst') control: any;`